# Angular project .sass fails to build

Tags: angular

I run into the following described below when I try to build or serve the angular app. The file is definitely there. What could cause this?

`ng build`

ERROR in multi ./src/styles.sass
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/konstantinwerhahn/Go/src/github.com/randomprofile/khw/src/styles.sass' in '/Users/konstantinwerhahn/Go/src/github.com/randomprofile/khw'

Comment: Is the path correct? Windows is case-sensitive if you're on Windows.

Comment: which version of Angular do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Ok very strange. I found the answer, but not the reason how it got there.

for some reason the extension was by default .sass and when changed to .scss then everything works.

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss" // default was: src/styles.sass
],
```